# Integrating Material UI Select input with Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have a custom Material UI multiple select input, the custom part of which allows it to be prepopulated with initial values, retrieved from a database (it loads them as selected items in the input), then a function named `handleChange` which allows the user to edit the selected elements (de-select/ remove elements which were loaded, and/or add new elements).

This all works in terms of rendering on screen how I need it to.  My issue is with what this outputs when I hit the submit button.

***Code:***

```
      import {
        FormControl,
        InputLabel,
        ListItemText,
        MenuItem,
        OutlinedInput,
        Select,
        Button,
      } from '@mui/material';
      import React from 'react';
      import { Formik } from 'formik';
      
      export default function Notifications() {
        const usersList = [
          { id: 1, FullName: 'Name1' },
          { id: 2, FullName: 'Name2' },
          { id: 3, FullName: 'Name3' },
          { id: 4, FullName: 'Name4' },
          { id: 5, FullName: 'Name5' },
        ];
      
        const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([
          { id: 2, FullName: 'Name2' },
          { id: 4, FullName: 'Name4' },
        ]);
      
        const submit = values => {
          console.log('values', values);
        };
      
        const handleChange = (event) => {
          const fullName = event.target.value.slice(-1).pop();
          const selectedPerson = usersList.find((u) => u.FullName === fullName);
      
          if (
            selectedPerson &&
            !personName.some((person) => person.FullName === fullName)
          ) {
            setPersonName((prevArray) => [...prevArray, selectedPerson]);
          } else {
            const updatedArray = personName.filter((p) => p.FullName !== fullName);
            console.log('updatedArray', updatedArray);
            setPersonName((prevArray) => [...updatedArray]);
          }
          console.log('event.target.value', event.target.value);
          console.log('personName', personName);
        };
      
        return (
          <Formik onSubmit={submit}>
            {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
              <div>
                <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 210 }} size="small">
                  <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Users</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
                    id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
                    multiple
                    value={personName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    input={<OutlinedInput label="Users" />}
                    renderValue={(selected) => {
                      return selected.map((s, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <MenuItem key={'menuItem' + index} value={s.id}>
                            <ListItemText
                              key={'listItemText' + index}
                              primary={s.FullName}
                            />
                          </MenuItem>
                        </div>
                      ));
                    }}
                  >
                    {usersList.map((name) => {
                      return (
                        <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name.FullName}>
                          <ListItemText primary={name.FullName} />
                        </MenuItem>
                      );
                    })}
                  </Select>
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </FormControl>
              </div>
            )}
          </Formik>
        );
      }
```

[And in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-panka-ktx06r?file=/src/App.js)

I need to integrate this with Formik but am really struggling (several days of trying now level of struggling).  It is set up to log the content of `values` (which I believe should be the correct name of the Formik values prop per the documentation [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeevent-any-void)), when the submit button is pressed.

I think it needs to use the Formik `setFieldValue` prop, perhaps calling that from the existing `onChange` prop (which currently calls the custom 'handleChange' function), but I'm not 100% sure, and I'm at a loss as to how exactly to do that if that is what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I've managed to get this to do what I need - the select field is pre-populated with initial values, its contents can then be edited by a user, and the selected values are passed to Formik's `value` prop. This was achieved using a combination of the `useFormik` hook, the `<Formik/>` component's `setFieldValue` prop and the `<Formik/>` component's `initialValues` prop.

Hopefully the below might help someone else in the future, as the Formik and MUI documentation is very limited, making this sort of thing really challenging.  As an aside, I noticed that Formik is not being supported by the developer any longer, so if anyone is reading this after April 2023 and just starting out (i.e. not committed lots of dev effort to Formik yet), then it'd be best to use a different library instead.

**Example:**
[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kare-5lzci4?file=/src/App.js)

**New Code:**

```
    import {
      FormControl,
      InputLabel,
      ListItemText,
      MenuItem,
      OutlinedInput,
      Select,
      Button,
    } from '@mui/material';
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useFormik } from 'formik';
    
    export default function Notifications() {
      const usersList = [
        { id: 1, FullName: 'Name1' },
        { id: 2, FullName: 'Name2' },
        { id: 3, FullName: 'Name3' },
        { id: 4, FullName: 'Name4' },
        { id: 5, FullName: 'Name5' },
      ];
    
      const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([
        { id: 2, FullName: 'Name2' },
        { id: 4, FullName: 'Name4' },
      ]);
    
      const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          members: personName,
        },
        onSubmit: (values) => {
          console.log('values', values);
        },
      });
    
      // This is needed to update the formik values prop every time personName changes - without this is doesn't update in a timely manner
      useEffect(() => {
        formik.setFieldValue('members', personName);
      }, [personName]);
    
      const handleChange = (event) => {
        const fullName = event.target.value.slice(-1).pop();
        const selectedPerson = usersList.find((u) => u.FullName === fullName);
        console.log('fullName', fullName)
    
        if (
          selectedPerson &&
          !personName.some((person) => person.FullName === fullName)
        ) {
          setPersonName((prevArray) => [...prevArray, selectedPerson]);
        } else {
          const updatedArray = personName.filter((p) => p.FullName !== fullName);
          console.log('updatedArray', updatedArray);
          setPersonName(updatedArray);
        }
        console.log('event.target.value', event.target.value);
        console.log('personName', personName);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 210 }} size="small">
            <InputLabel id="multiple-checkbox-label">Members</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="multiple-checkbox-label"
              id="multiple-checkbox"
              multiple
              value={personName.map((p) => p.FullName)}
              //value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Members" />}
              renderValue={(selected) => {
                return selected.map((s, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <MenuItem key={'menuItem' + index} value={s}>
                      <ListItemText
                        key={'listItemText' + index}
                        primary={s}
                      />
                    </MenuItem>
                  </div>
                ));
              }}
            >
              {usersList.map((name) => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name.FullName}>
                    <ListItemText primary={name.FullName} />
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })}
            </Select>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
         
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
```